# RabbitMQ X-delayed plugin : How to access processing data in exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm searching for few hours now about how to retrieve informations in a RabbitMQ exchange.

Let me explain my goal :

I designed a system to avoid burning gmail API calls limits (per second) in my application. To do so I set up a cron which scale the sendings in an hour : basically I defined a delay in my cron and then push my data into a delayed-queue which is itself bound to the x-delayed-exchanger (type **direct**). This part is working pretty well.

In addition, I have a consumer which consumes and send the emails from my queue. It's perfectly working too.

My problem come here : Some manual actions coming from my users need to be send ASAP. That so, I want to retrieve the few next delayed messages which are going to be sent from my delayed exchange to the queue and put this new message between the two next delayed message :

As an example : 
my-delayed-exchange has `[message1: will be published in 3000ms, message2: will be published in 6000ms]`: I want to insert `messageToSendAsap: will be published in 4500ms]` that way I'll be insure that I control my API limits.

Does anyone hear about a method to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance
PS : I code in NodeJS with the amqp lib

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example on the [github page of the plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange),  you can simply set the `x-delay` value to 1 (I think it cannot be zero). That is if you are sending message M1 with delay of X and message M2 with delay of Y, so that Y < X the message M2 will be delivered to queue(s) before M1.

Also if you want the message to be sent right away (so not in-between the next two as you wrote in your example) you can simply have another "classical" direct exchnage (without any delays).